# why is my while loop being skipped? values were not met yet

Tags: java, while-loop, int

so the code section i have below - what it is meant to do eventually - is make a  tree. the area i am currently having a problem with, is getting the user to answer wants decorations, or not.   I would like the while loop to keep making the user inputting a value until the number is equal to 1 or 0. but what it does, is it uses the "  int decorations = s.nextInt(); " outside of the loop, and just skips the while.

.

.

the section that is not working is a very important part, and my code will not run without it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

/*
    __________________________________INPUTS_____________________________________
*/    

      //Tree
    System.out.println("Tree size");
    int tree = s.nextInt();
```

problem starts here

```
      //Decorations

    System.out.println("Decorations");
    int decorations = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    while (decorations < 2 && decorations > -1){
      System.out.println("(y = 1 || n = 0) ");
      decorations = s.nextInt();
    }
```

problem ends ^^^

i have tried to write the code with an if inside of the while, and making the while repeat until a boolean is set to true

```
int tf = 0;
  while (tf != true){
    System.out.println("(y = 1 || n = 0) ");
    int decorations = s.nextInt();
    if(decorations == 1 || decorations == 0 ){
      decor = true;  
    }
  }
```

can i please have some suggestions on what to fix?  im still very new to java. thanks for any help

Comment: `while (decorations < 2 && decorations > -1)` is the same as `while (decorations ==1 || decorations == 0)`, so exactly the **opposite** of what you want. Perhaps you mean to write `while (decorations >= 2 || decorations <= -1)` or `while (decorations > 1 || decorations < 0)` or even `while (decorations !=1 && decorations != 0)`?

Comment: Would help to know what decorations is.  Try changing the empty print in your 'problem starts/ends here' code to: System.out.println("before while loop, decorations="+decorations);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you share a sample input and output of your problem?

If you want this :

"I would like the while loop to keep making the user inputting a value until the number is equal to 1 or 0."

This could do :

```
  int decorations = s.nextInt();
    while(decorations != 1 && decorations !=0){
       System.out.println("(y = 1 || n = 0) ");
       decorations = s.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: Clarification question should be done as a comment, not as an answer. Wait until you have the [50 rep needed to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (you're almost there). Until then, delete this answer to clear the negative rep it is giving you.

Comment: @Andreas  I am also putting my answer as per my understanding of the question.

Comment: when typing out that section i completely forgot that i could use the NotEqual to there. thanks @kaizen, and others for the help!

Comment: That loop will never exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (decorations < 2 && decorations > -1){
  System.out.println("(y = 1 || n = 0) ");
  decorations = s.nextInt();
}
```

You want to keep looping while the input is invalid. But if `decorations` is less than 2 and greater than -1, the input is valid. So your test is backwards.

Answer (score 0):

The second code you are comparing an int with a boolean

you need to change the flag("tf") to boolean

```
boolean tf = false;
while(!tf) { // by using ! we can get the oposite
 tf = decorations == 1 || decorations == 0 ? true : false;
 // do your code
}
```

the ternary ? : is an if else in one line, this is the equivalent

```
if(decorations == 1 || decorations == 0) 
    tf = true;
else
    tf = false;
```